# Vuforia - Advance Model Target doesn't work on Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've create with the Model Target Generator provided by Vuforia, a model Target Database within which my printed model with an Advance View.

When I build an Android Application the Engine found the model and show the augmented elements, but if I use the same database inside Hololens application doesn't track the model.

I tried the same database and logic on Android device and it's work.
I want the same to happen on the Hololens.

Comment: Are you using a custom app or a Vuforia sample app. If the first I would try with the Hololens sample and check if the target works there

Comment: First I was using Hololens sample with Vuforia, and the model is tracked only with GuideView. After I tried to create a new project but I have the same problem.

Comment: If you followed the steps described here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/working-hololens-sample-unity and still does not work, then I would file a bug report here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine